# Erro parameter index out of range (1> number of parameters which is 0)

Tags: java, sql, banco-de-dados, jdbc, prepared-statement

Estou estudando *JDBC* e aprendendo como funciona o **resultset** e **statement**, fiz primeiro o método de adicionar e alterar dados com o statement que funcionou perfeitamente

```
private void jBtnGravarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    String Produto = jTextNomeProduto.getText();
    String Marca = jTextMarca.getText();
    String Estoque = jTextEstoque.getText();
    String Preco = jTextPreço.getText();
    String Fornecedor = jTextFornecedor.getText();
    String command;
    String msg;
            
    try {
        if(jLblCodl.getText().equals("")){
            command = "insert into produtos (NProduto, Marca , Estoque , Preco, Fornecedor) values ('" + Produto + "','" + Marca + "','" + Estoque + "','" + Preco + "','" + Fornecedor + "')";
            msg = "Gravação de novo registro realizada com sucesso";
        } else { 
            command = "update produtos set NProduto ='" + Produto + "'," + "Marca = '" + Marca + "'," + "Estoque  = '" + Estoque + "'," + "Preco = '" + Preco + "'," + "Fornecedor = '" + Fornecedor + "' where Cod = " + jLblCodl.getText();
            msg = "Alteração realizada com sucesso";
        }
        con_produtos.statement.executeUpdate(command);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg );
    } catch(SQLException err) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "\nErro na gravação!\nErro: " + err);
    }
    position();
}
```

Após isso tentei usar o *PreparedStatement* e sem usar concatenação nos comandos sql:

```
private void jBtnGravarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    String sql;
    String msg;
    try {
        if(jLblCodl.getText().equals("")){
            sql = "insert into produtos (NProduto, Marca , Estoque , Preco, Fornecedor) values (?,?,?,?,?);";
            msg = "Gravação de novo registro realizada com sucesso";
        } else { 
            sql = "update produtos set NProduto = ?, Marca = ?, Estoque = ?, Preco = ?, Fornecedor = ? Where Cod = ? ;";
            msg = "Alteração realizada com sucesso";
        }
        con_produtos.statement.setString(1, jTextNomeProduto.getText());
        con_produtos.statement.setString(2,  jTextMarca.getText());
        con_produtos.statement.setInt(3, Integer.parseInt(jTextEstoque.getText()) );
        con_produtos.statement.setDouble(4, Double.valueOf(jTextPreço.getText()));
        con_produtos.statement.setString(5, jTextFornecedor.getText());
        System.out.println();
        con_produtos.statement.executeUpdate(sql);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg );
    } catch(SQLException err) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "\nErro na gravação!\nErro: " + err);
    }
    con_produtos.execSQL("select * from produtos order by Cod");
    position();
}
```

Mas se executo ele retorna o erro
**parameter index out of range (1> number of parameters which is 0)**

```
public void execSQL(String sql) {
    try {
        statement = conec.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = statement.executeQuery();
    } catch (SQLException excecao) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "\nErro no comando SQL!\nErro: " + excecao + "\nComando SQL passado: " + sql);
    }    
}
```

Este é o método onde executa a query
Sobre a parte de faltar a declaração do statement eu fiz da seguinte forma
Sobre faltar a declaração do statement eu declarei da seguinte forma

```
publicJFrameIndex() {
        initComponents();
        con_produtos = new Conectar();
        con_produtos.getConnection();
        con_produtos.execSQL("select * from produtos order by Cod"); 
}
```

Comment: No seu *listener* você está fazendo *binding* de parâmetros em `con_produtos.statement`, porém o seu código não está mostrando onde esse `statement` está sendo criado. O que muito provavelmente está acontecendo é que o `PreparedStatement` não está sendo inicializado corretamente. Isso é, está faltando um `con_produtos.statement = conec.prepareStatement(sql)` antes do primeiro `con_produtos.statement.setString`.

Comment: Um outro ponto importante que foge ao escopo da pergunta é que amarrar código de UI com o código de acesso ao banco é uma má prática. Para desacoplar o código vale a pena introduzir um *Repository* ou *[DAO](https://pt.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objeto_de_acesso_a_dados)*.

Comment: a inicialização do statement a que você se refere é o último bloco que adicionei acima?
Irei estudar também sobre DAO, estou utilizando o código com a ui apenas para testes e estudo

Comment: ja fiz vários testes e n vejo o erro em lugar algum, esse é o problema de ser iniciante em programação hehe

Comment: Oi Gabriel. Não, o que eu quis dizer é o código que inicializa o `statement`. O problema é que o código está incompleto (leia mais sobre como criar um [MVCE](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)). Você já tentou incluir `con_produtos.statement = conec.prepareStatement(sql)` na linha antes de `con_produtos.statement.setString(1, jTextNomeProduto.getText());` conforme meu comentário acima?

Comment: Entendi agora o que quis dizer, tentei el ele me retorna o seguinte erro: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near'?,?,?,?,?)' at line 1`

Comment: adicionei aspas simples entre os valores ficando assim `values ('?','?','?','?','?')` e ele volta a me retornar o erro **parameter index out of range (1> number of parameters which is 0)**

Comment: Novamente, a melhor linha de ação para debugar é construir um MVCE que eu possa rodar para reproduzir o problema (se não o processo de troubleshooting vira um jogo de adivinhação sem muito benefício para a comunidade como um todo). A primeira mensagem de erro significa que o binding de parâmetros não está funcionando. Acredito que o problema seja a chamada sobrecarregada com a String `sql` em `con_produtos.statement.executeUpdate(sql)`. Ao invés disso, execute a chamada sem parâmetros `con_produtos.statement.executeUpdate()`, assim ele usará a consulta preparada com os parâmetros carregados.

Comment: Recomecei do zero e com menos entradas, apenas 2 campos e dava o mesmo erro então retirei a string  `sql` do `con_produtos.statement.executeUpdate()`, resolveu o problema, procurei o porque disso acontecer e descobri que quando se usa a string com o comando SQL no `prepareStatement` basta usar o `executeUpdate` sem parâmetros que já ira funcionar o cadastro. **Muito obrigado pela ajuda**. Agora irei procurar conhecer sobre DAO como você sugeriu